# SQLite Xamarin.forms dosn't return the saved Data

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I stuck with Xamarin.Forms SQLite.

i use this NuGet package : sqlite-net-pcl

[My SQLITE Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRJV7.png)

I want to save the Data from my Table to a Variable with this following code

```
        SQLiteConnection myconnection = new SQLiteConnection(Constants.DatabasePath);

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(myconnection);
        myconnection.CreateTable<Modul>();

        var Mods = myconnection.Query<Modul>("SELECT * FROM Modul");
```

Mods returns with = Count=0;
[But i have saved Data. Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNxj5.png)

My modul class:
MoulID has Primary Key on Top [Primarykey]...

```
   public int ModulID { get; set; }

    public string Modul_Name { get; set; }
```

I will include my existing Database from [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBC5b.png)

with this class

public class{

```
   public const string DatabaseFilename = "VocalDB.db";



    public static string DatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = "D:/C#-Projets/Vocabul/Vocabul/Vocabul/DataBase/";
            return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseFilename);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: are you saving data from within your app?  Or are you pre-populating the db with data using a query tool?

Comment: i have saved mock data to my db SQLitestudio. And i want simply read the data from Xamarin.Forms in my db. Later i want display the data in my app.

Comment: If you want to include an existing db in your app, you generally need to copy it from the app bundle to a writable path at startup.  If a db does not already exist at your path, SQLiteConnection will create an emtpy db for you.  This is probably what is happening.

Comment: Thank you. When i give the SQLiteconnection the path to my Database: (cannot open)

Comment: What path are you using?  If you are getting an error, then how were you able to execute a query in your original post?

Comment: i refreshed the post

Comment: an iOS/Android app cannot access a path on your desktop's D:\ drive at runtime.  How could this possibly work?  If you want to include an existing db in your app, you have to add it to the app bundle and then copy if to a writable path at startup.  Which I already explained to you.

Comment: Okay, i'm new in Xamarin. Can you give me a tutorial or reference to learn?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create the table then you execute the query... I think the table is empty after you have created it.

```
  myconnection.CreateTable<Modul>();

        var Mods = myconnection.Query<Modul>("SELECT * FROM Modul");
```